# Changing Dimension of a player in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I exited Minecraft while in the Twilight Forest and when the world loads, it crashes. I've been looking through level.dat but to no avail. How would I change the dimension of my player to the overworld?

Answer (score 3):

The player information (including location and dimension) is stored in the [Player.dat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format) file.

It's named by the GUID which you can get from the logs when you log in (if on a server) or it's the only file in the saves/*World name*/playerdata folder in singleplayer.

The relevant NBT tag is the Dimension one.

Comment: Thus far I have come across two player.dat files. One was clearly related to a specific mod I have installed, and the other seemingly has no data stored (as it has 0 KB) and is just a placeholder. I have checked the files thoroughly, and I don't believe there is another. The one I am attempting to open is in the "NEI" folder.

Comment: Is it singleplayer or multiplayer? In my world it's 'playerdata/7d435117-678a-47f3-b42a-742d97ded9cf.dat'

Comment: Singleplayer. However I have found the file you were referring to now. I was looking at NEI rather than playerdata. I've now changed the dimension id, but 0 hasn't brought about any changes. Thoughts?

Comment: Stop the game, not just unload but quit it completely. Then open and save it (close the editor to be sure) and restart it, minecraft is a bit tricky about such things unfortunately.

Answer (score -5):

I'm assuming that here dimension means biome. If that's correct then you can create another world and if your game crashes then you can lower the video details like render distance and particles to minimal, set clouds to off also installing Optifine mod may fix your issue.

Peace!

Comment: Afraid not, I have loaded multiple other worlds after this problematic one. I believe something in the Twilight Forest **dimension** is requiring more attention than can be given, and effectively crashes my client.

Comment: Does reinstall help?

Comment: It can be due to corrupt files.

Comment: It is the world itself, the client has not presented any issues.